# Why is my object not rendering with details?

Tags: rendering, lighting, shadows

I've made a toothpaste tube and lid, and i've gone through all the settings I know about (i'm still getting used to blender). For some reason the details are washed out in the render and I don't know why. I've bellow the difference in detail/shadows you can see when rendered.

[image]

[image]

Comment: You are using very flat lighting, where you have the same brightness coming from all directions. Try using a more directional light, and bring down the brightess of the environment, so that you have more contrast between the bright and dark areas of the image.

Comment: Use HDRI lights